# Error creating brands through API on demo system

Tags: docusignapi

I am dual-posting this here while I wait for DocuSign support to get around to assisting in the hopes someone here has some more insight.

---

Our application uses the DocuSignConnect API to manage brands. It has been in production for years and worked without issues. Sometime last week, our API calls to create brands began failing, but only on the Demo system. This functionality is continuing to work fine in the Production system. There are no code differences between our Demo and Prod environments.

In the past, we have seen issues (of a different kind) when changes are rolled out to the DocuSign Demo system. I wonder if this could be one of those scenarios.

The details are limited. Our API calls to create a brand are met with a failure with the following properties:

```
ErrorCode: 309

ErrorReason: Brands could not be created.

faultString: Brands could not be created. Unable to upload brand, error: Must specify valid information for parsing in the string.
```

As I mentioned above, our application has not changed recently with respect to the DocuSignConnect API. I have noticed, however, that the Signing and Email resource xml files appear to be undergoing a change (they differ significantly between DocuSign's Prod and Demo sites.) Perhaps this is a clue behind the fairly unhelpful "...specify valid information for parsing..." message.

My concern is that something is soon to be deployed to Production that will break our application.

I should add that our other API calls seem to be ok (sending envelopes, for example)

Has anyone experienced this type of problem creating brands?

Comment: If it used to work fine earlier and no changes were done on your end, and now its not working then I would suggest you to contact DS Support team, and they will be able to help you in knowing the root cause.

Comment: @AmitKBist thanks...I had already done that.  I was looking for community assistance while I waited for DocuSign response.  "...I am dual-posting this here while I wait for DocuSign support to get around to assisting in the hopes someone here has some more insight...."

Comment: Can you share brand creation code, normally `Must specify valid information for parsing in the string` error comes when you are sending string value which cannot be mapped to an enum on the called method

Comment: In this case (see my posted answer), there was an XML attribute that went from 'optional' in prod to 'required' in demo.  Our code was not including that attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update on this from DocuSign support is that the 'type' attribute on the 'logo' element that is part of the XML schema defined in the 'CreateBrand' API call has changed from optional (in their PROD environment) to required (in their DEMO environment).

They are probably going to be changing their DEMO code to revert this attribute back to 'optional' before it is deployed to their PROD system.

But in any event, our code is going to change to start including the 'type' attribute on the 'logo' elements to ensure success going forward regardless.